# ShadowProperties being reached by foreach before being created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm learning atm with the Pluralsight courses from Julie Lerman. I'm watching the 2nd course "[Entity Framework Core 2: Mappings](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/e-f-core-2-beyond-the-basics-mappings)" but I'm using EF Core 2.1.

Edit:
So I decided comment everything out and follow the course again and it is working now BUT the generated migration in generating 2 columns that shouldn't be there:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "BetterName_Created",
                table: "Samurais",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "GivenName",
                table: "Samurais",
                nullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "BetterName_LastModified",
                table: "Samurais",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "SurName",
                table: "Samurais",
                nullable: true);
}
```

SamuraiContext.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SamuraiBattle>().HasKey(s => new { s.SamuraiId, s.BattleId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Battle>().Property(b => b.StartDate).HasColumnType("Date");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Battle>().Property(b => b.EndDate).HasColumnType("Date");

    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property<DateTime>("Created");  
        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property<DateTime>("LastModified");
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Samurai>().OwnsOne(s => s.BetterName).Property(b => b.GivenName).HasColumnName("GivenName");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Samurai>().OwnsOne(s => s.BetterName).Property(b => b.SurName).HasColumnName("SurName");
}
```

the foreach context has been build already before I add the GivenName/Surname, until that everything is working as intended. But after adding the last 2 rows for the column name it adds BetterName_Created and BetterName_LastModified why? (according to the course it shouldn't)

PersonFullName.cs

```
public class PersonFullName
{
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{GivenName} {SurName}";
    public string FullNameReverse => $"{SurName}, {GivenName}";

    public PersonFullName(string givenName, string surName)
    {
        SurName = surName;
        GivenName = givenName;
    }
}
```

Samurai.cs

```
public class Samurai
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonFullName BetterName { get; set; }
    public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    public List<SamuraiBattle> SamuraiBattles { get; set; }
    public SecretIdentity SecretIdentity { get; set; }

    public Samurai()
    {
        Quotes = new List<Quote>();
        SamuraiBattles = new List<SamuraiBattle>();
    }
}
```

Best regards,
Adriano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `foreach` loop defines shadow properties for owned entities as well. Remember that by the EF Core terminology owned entities are still entities, so `GetEntityTypes()` includes them in the result set.

EF Core provides [`IsOwned`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.isowned?view=efcore-2.1) extension method which can be used to identify them and do special processing, or in this particular case, just skip them:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => !t.IsOwned())
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, such loops should be after discovering all entity and owned entity types. In case `PersonFullName` is not marked with `[Owned`] attribute,  move the `foreach` after the `OwnsOne` calls (or better at the end of the `OnModelCreating`).

Comment: Thank you very mutch, tried both ways and both worked.