# Owned Entities when updating efCore from 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.1

I'm migrating an existing project based on DDD design principles from efcore 2.2 to efcore 3.1. Database setup is based on the series of articles that Julie Lerman wrote a few years ago.

Generally this has been fine but I'm struggle to resolve an issued with owned entities and in particular this error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: The type 'ApplicationCore.Entities.UserAggregate.Email' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists
```

The two entities are:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid GuidId { get; private set; }
    public Email Email {get; private set;}
}
```

and it's "owned" entity

```
public class Email
{
    public string Address { get; private set; }
}
```

Formerly in EfCore 2.2 the configuration was:

```
private static void ConfigureUser(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);

    builder.Property(s => s.GuidId)
            .IsRequired();

    builder.OwnsOne(u => u.Email);
}
```

As far as I understand what I should be doing in efcore3.1 is to update this to be:

```
private static void ConfigureUser(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);

    builder.Property(s => s.GuidId)
            .IsRequired();

    builder.OwnsOne(u => u.Email).WithOwner();
}
```

As well as this configure method there are several more for the other entities within the `OnModelCreating()` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<ForecastSetup>(ConfigureForecastSetup);
    …
    builder.Entity<User>(ConfigureUser);

    // Remove internal property
    foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        builder.Entity(entityType.Name).Ignore("IsDirty");
    }
}
```

The exception will be thrown from the `builder.Entity(entityType.Name).Ignore("IsDirty")` line.

And that's it. However, this makes zero difference and the same error reappears.

I can't run add-migrations to test if there is something else being setup as the exception is being thrown and I'm unsure as to what will happen if I delete the ContextModelSnapshot…

Comment: Somewhere in the code not shown here you have `modelBuilder.Entity()` call with  `Email` type as argument/generic type argument. You can try to run a simple query like `context.Users.ToLIst()` in VS debugger with break on exception thrown, and see the exact line generating the exception.

Comment: Ah, so in my `OnModelCreating()` method, there are all of the Configure methods, then it loops through all of the entities in build.Model to remove a property which isn't required. I'll update the question to make this part more explicity

Comment: Most likely you need to exclude entity types with `IsOwned()` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888876/shadowproperties-being-reached-by-foreach-before-being-created/52890860#52890860

Comment: Genius! that's the one :-) I'll add this in as an answer, cheers. I'd been filtering on the name of the type itself to exclude them yesterday; but there could have been other config problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @IvanStoev, see the question he links to in the comments.

The config was correct, my problem was occur when trying to remove the Shadow property

```
// Remove shadow property for entities which are not owned
foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(e => !e.IsOwned()))
{
    builder.Entity(entityType.Name).Ignore("IsDirty");
}
```